# Complex numbers - Quadratic formula?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Let a and b be real numbers. The complex number 4 - 5i is a root of the quadratic $z^2 + (a + 8i) z + (-39 + bi) = 0$. What is the other root?

I did a lot of work on hand and plugging this into the quadratic formula and with wolfram alpha but it doesn't simplify itself easily at all....anyone have any help to offer? Thanks!

Comment: how did you make use of given data that $4-5i $ is a root?

Comment: Well I set the stuff plugged into the quadratic formula equal to it...but I don't see how I can proceed (not to mention there's a +/- sign and I don't know which one it is, positive or negative)

Comment: If you have a $\pm$ sign, that means there are two solutions, one with $+$ and one with $-$.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know whether 4-5i is the positive one or the negative one?

Comment: Thanks guys for all the answers and the hints it helps :D

Comment: On the complex plane, you don't have something like "positive" or "negative" - you can apply those terms only to the real and imaginary part of a complex number on their own, because $\Bbb{C}$ is not ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$(4-5i)^2+(a+8i)(4-5i)+(-39+bi)=0$$$$\iff (4a-8)+(-5a+b-8)i=0,$$
we have
$$4a-8=-5a+b-8=0\iff a=2,b=18.$$

Also, you'll have
$$z^2+(2+8i)z+(-39+18i)=\{z-(4-5i)\}\{z-(-6-3i)\}.$$
So, what you want is $z=-6-3i$.

You can find this transformation by setting $\{z-(4-5i)\}\{z-(c+di)\}.$

Comment: You are welcome! My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Let the other root be $u+iv$ where $u,v$ are real

Using Vieta's formula $\displaystyle u+iv+4-5i=-a-8i\iff -a-8i=u+4-i(5-v)$

Comparing the real & the imaginary parts,

$\displaystyle  u+4=-a\iff u=-a-4$ and $5-v=8\iff v=-3$

Again, $\displaystyle(u+iv)(4-5i)=-39+bi\iff -(a+4+3i)(4-5i)=-(39-ib)$

Multiply & compare the real & the imaginary parts

Comment: Thanks a lot that made it clearer xD